# How to perform AND operation in between two OR_LIKE queries in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I perform a multiple search using multiple join query in code igniter so i perform 3 or_like query.But there is an 'OR' placed in between each or_like query by default by code igniter.But actualy i want to perform 'AND' Operation Between them.Please help me.
                   Thanks

Comment: can you please post some of your code s??

Comment: show your query and then ask your question. Also if you tell what you want as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it very simply in codeigniter version 3.0

eg,

```
    $this ->db ->select('*');
    $this ->db ->where('age',$age);
    $this ->db ->where('country',$country);
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this ->db ->or_where('state',$state);
    $this ->db ->or_where('district',$district);
    $this->db->group_end();
    $query=$this ->db ->get('pg_reg');
```

Answer (score 0):

or_like is provided by codeignitor to multiple instances are joined by OR. So, I think there is no way to replace OR by AND. Here is another solution that you can try.

Instead using "like" and "or_like" use where clause as below

```
$this->db->where('location LIKE', '%'.$your_location.'%');
$this->db->where('city LIKE', '%'.$your_city.'%');
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `pg_personaldet` `pe` LEFT JOIN `pg_reg` `r` ON `r`.`rid`=`pe`.`rid` LEFT JOIN `pg_education` `ed` ON `ed`.`rid`=`pe`.`rid` WHERE `ed`.`education` LIKE '%3%' AND `ed`.`education` LIKE '%9%' AND `ed`.`occupation` LIKE '%17%'  According to your code i get this code but i need OR between like operation  in education table and Occupation table and perform AND operation between education and Occupation table.In my program '$your_location'  is  array elements(ie,$arr[$i] in for loop and this query performed in that Loop).

Comment: I could not see any Occupation table in your query. Can you add piece of query code by editing question ? So it will help more to debug it.